# Pagefile cannot be located on any drive but C

Tags: windows-10, memory, pagefile

I'm facing a rather weird issue with Windows 10 Pro 21H1 19043.1151: apparently, it refuses to allocate the pagefile on any drive but C.

I'm using a custom-built configuration that includes a 240 GiB scratch disk in addition to 32 GiB of physical memory. Said scratch disk is partitioned into two equal parts, with one of them being intended to be occupied by the Windows pagefile. However, despite me setting a system-managed pagefile for the drive, or setting it to a specific size, after a reboot, the pagefile is gone from the scratch disk, and only the nominal pagefile I left on the system partition remains. If I disable the pagefile on C, the usual error about a missing pagefile pops up.

Not sure what gives here, why the system isn't respecting the pagefile settings I specify. Any ideas?

Comment: The trick used to be to set a tiny pagefile on C: of some few MB, then set the main one as desired. I don't know if this still works.

Comment: @Tetsujin tried that, I'm afraid it doesn't. On reboot, the "main" pagefile on the separate drive is still gone, and now Windows thinks everything's good, until it runs out of memory (yes, I do some *very* heavy lifting from time to time).